# Why does conversion between GregorianCalendar and OffsetDateTime fail when evaluating the ZoneInfo part?

Tags: java, gregorian-calendar

I am converting an OffsetDateTime to a GregorianCalendar as part of populating values for an outbound web service.  I just thought I'd test the actual conversion.

It is failing and i don't understand why - here is the test method:

```
@Test
public void testOffsetDateTimeToGregorianCalendar() {
    // given the current gregorian utc time
    GregorianCalendar expectedGregorianUtcNow = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    OffsetDateTime expectedUtcOffsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.from(expectedGregorianUtcNow.toZonedDateTime());

    // when converting to a GregorianCalendar
    GregorianCalendar actualGregorianUtcNow = GregorianCalendar.from(expectedUtcOffsetDateTime.toZonedDateTime());

    // then make sure we got the correct value
    assertThat(actualGregorianUtcNow, equalTo(expectedGregorianUtcNow));
}
```

within the equalto, the comparison fails in the evaluation of the gregorianCutover.  Why?  Is this a bug?

it looks like actual has:
gregorianCutover = -9223372036854775808
and expected has:
gregorianCutover = -12219292800000

Everything else is correct as can be seen in the unit test output (gregorianCutover does not appear there):

```
    java.lang.AssertionError: 
    Expected:<java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1458667828375,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="UTC",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=2,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=4,ERA=1,YEAR=2016,MONTH=2,WEEK_OF_YEAR=12,WEEK_OF_MONTH=4,DAY_OF_MONTH=22,DAY_OF_YEAR=82,DAY_OF_WEEK=3,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=4,AM_PM=1,HOUR=5,HOUR_OF_DAY=17,MINUTE=30,SECOND=28,MILLISECOND=375,ZONE_OFFSET=0,DST_OFFSET=0]>
    but: was <java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1458667828375,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="UTC",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=2,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=4,ERA=1,YEAR=2016,MONTH=2,WEEK_OF_YEAR=12,WEEK_OF_MONTH=4,DAY_OF_MONTH=22,DAY_OF_YEAR=82,DAY_OF_WEEK=3,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=4,AM_PM=1,HOUR=5,HOUR_OF_DAY=17,MINUTE=30,SECOND=28,MILLISECOND=375,ZONE_OFFSET=0,DST_OFFSET=0]>
```

Did i do something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, as far as I'm aware, `java.time` doesn't try to model a Gregorian cutover - so when an `OffsetDateTime` is converted back to a `GregorianCalendar`, that's done by modeling it as having a Gregorian calendar with a cutover back at the start of time. Hence the documentation for `GregorianCalendar.from(ZoneDateTime)`:

> Since `ZonedDateTime` does not support a Julian-Gregorian cutover date and uses ISO calendar system, the return `GregorianCalendar` is a pure Gregorian calendar and uses ISO 8601 standard for week definitions, which has MONDAY as the `FirstDayOfWeek` and 4 as the value of the `MinimalDaysInFirstWeek`.

Ideally, I'd suggest that you avoid using `java.util.*` in terms of date/time API... stick with `java.time` everywhere. But if you really need to, I'd probably suggest just not using `GregorianCalendar.equals` for testing equality - check the instant in time and the time zone separately, if those are the things you're interested in.

Comment: thanks...  i will stay away from the equals method, but staying away from the api is not a possibility because when you try to integrate to a web service generated from jaxb, the generated DateTimeOffset factory requires you to provide it with a GregorianCalendar